# Pulling google analytics data into Asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

I am new to Asp.net and does any one have a working solution to pulling data from google analytics into my webapplication, I have obtained the following code but it gives me an IO error.

Here is my method:

```
public void Main()
        {
            //This is the API url which we're storing to a string
            string scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.GetStringValue();

            //For whatever reason, this is labelled wrong. It is the email address
            //that you have added as a user to your Analytics account

            string clientId = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";


            //This is the physical path to the file we downloaded earlier
            //To demonstrate this, I've kept the full path to my key file.
            //Obviously, you will need to change this to match where you've
            //stored yours.
            string keyFile = @"C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Adwords and analytics\katoona\793c6491a4ad1118dda49d6bf6824a975edd485a-privatekey.p12";

            //The password Google gives you, probably the same as the one below
            string keyPassword = "notasecret";


            //Store the authentication description
            AuthorizationServerDescription desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;

            //Create a certificate object to use when authenticating
            X509Certificate2 key = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            //Now, we will log in and authenticate, passing in the description
            //and key from above, then setting the accountId and scope
            AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key)
            {
                ServiceAccountId = clientId,
                Scope = scope
            };

            //Finally, complete the authentication process
            //NOTE: This is the first change from the update above
            OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> auth =
                new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

            //First, create a new service object
            //NOTE: this is the second change from the update
            //above. Thanks to James for pointing this out
            AnalyticsService gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { Authenticator = auth });

            //Create our query
            //The Data.Ga.Get needs the parameters:
            //Analytics account id, starting with ga:
            //Start date in format YYYY-MM-DD
            //End date in format YYYY-MM-DD
            //A string specifying the metrics
            DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:9475327", "2013-09-09", "2013-09-23", "ga:visitors");

            //Specify some addition query parameters
            r.Dimensions = "ga:visitorType";
            r.Sort = "-ga:visitors";
            r.MaxResults = 5;

            //Execute and fetch the results of our query
            try
            {
                //Write the column headers
                GaData d = r.Execute();

                foreach (var h in d.ColumnHeaders)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(h.Name);
                }

                //Write the data
                foreach (var row in d.Rows)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(row[0] + " ------ " + row[1]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception webEx)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

Comment: Giving the exact error received would help - then we can see whether it's an OAuth problem or a problem with what you're sending to query the GA data API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the exact error received would help - then we can see whether it's an OAuth problem or a problem with what you're sending to query the GA data API.

Also, start by using the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to construct and test your query before converting it to C# code.

Comment: Thanks for the google query explorer link it helped me gain insight i have scrapped the above code and installed the google analytics nuget package but i am now facing authotization problems.Where do i obtain the required fields:           `<appSettings>
    <add key="Google.Analytics.AppName" value="JacobAnalytics" />
    <add key="Google.Analytics.UserName" value="xxxxx@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="Google.Analytics.AppKey" value="appkey" />
    <add key="Google.Analytics.ProfileId" value="ga:######" />
    <add key="Google.Analytics.AccountId" value="UA-{######}" />
  </appSettings>`